# Why does grep not return the from line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, smtp

Asked on another forum - no answer yet so I thought I would ask here.
I had to escape the backslashes in the grep lines to make the backslash show up in this post.

I have this but grep is not returning the from line. It is something to do with the relay= part of the line. 
If I modify it to say `relay=exampleXXX111.examplf.ex.examplf.com`, it outputs the line just fine.

There are other ways to get this info, but I would like an explanation for this specific example.

> echo "Apr 4 05:00:24 example sendmail[3365]: x3440OxC003366: from=, size=10181, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<4E94014993C44528C502E32E3239E0B@example.XX.example.com>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=exampleXXX111.examplf.ex.example.com [10.100.10.10]" | grep -v "to=.*\.example\.com"

**NO OUTPUT**

---

> echo "Apr 4 05:00:24 example sendmail[3365]: x3440OxC003366: from=, size=10181, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<4E94014993C44528C502E32E3239E0B@example.XX.example.com>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=exampleXXX112.examplf.ex.examplf.com [10.100.10.10]" | grep -v "to=.*\.example\.com"

**OUTPUT:**

> Apr 4 05:00:24 example sendmail[3365]: x3440OxC003366: from=, size=10181, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<4E94014993C44528C502E32E3239E0B@example.XX.example.com>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=exampleXXX112.examplf.ex.examplf.com [10.100.10.10]

Comment: Please do some formatting according to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example contains pro**to=** SMTP, ... ex **.example.com**, so the grep condition is triggered and the -v will suppress the line.

Using `grep -v '\sto=.*.example.com'` should do the trick.

Comment: I did not see that, must have had my beer goggles on.
Thank you for that.